# What can I get from the Import Room?

Tags: shantae-riskys-revenge

In Scuttle Town, there is an Import Room, and I can apparently get "things from lands beyond" here, but there is never anything for me.

How can I use this room? What do I get if I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Import Room allows you to get gems if you've played another DSiWare title by WayForward, Mighty Flip Champs, the gem bonus is as follows, according to [this GameFAQs answer](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/974895-shantae-riskys-revenge/answers?qid=230818):

> Having MFC - 100 Gems
>   Beating MFC - 200 Gems
>   All S-Ranks on MFC - 300 Gems